# Ubuntu terminal : cd directory returning directory name with backslash.Why?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I have got only one folder named "My_Folder" in my home directory.When i use terminal to change directory:

```
cd My //after entering My when I press TAB
```

this returns...

```
cd \My_Folder/
```

It changes directory to My_Folder but why this happens?

I would like it to return like this (usual way):

```
cd My_Folder/
```

Comment: Is there a space after backslash ? `cd \ My_Folder/` The folder name might contain a leading space.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia no.